# Sending system events to confluence

Tags: confluence

Our organization is moving toward using Atlassian's confluence for documentation.

I'd like to reduce the e-mail crush, and send notifications of some events that currently go to e-mail to a Confluence blog instead.

Has anyone had any success doing this?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is RTFM?

Confluence can ingest email ever since 1.3

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Mail+Archiving+FAQ

Answer (score 0):

I like the confluence ability to {html-include} and also {sql} queries for pulling data into the wiki.

In addition:

- Sending mail to confluence as a repository.
- XML-RPC to create or update pages automaticly.
- Users can subscribe to a page and get e-mail notification when things change.

There's also a bunch of plug-ins which might be usefull.

References:
 http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Remote+API+Specification

Cheers :-)